# Angular2 ng-toasty ErrorHandler

Tags: angular, toast, custom-error-handling

I'm trying to use an implementation of ErrorHandler to publish a toast when I handle global errors. The problem is that the toast never pops up. I have a console.log in the publishToast method that is showing in the console and no other errors are appearing.

If I create the same publishToast method in a component the toast works fine so it seems to be something to do with the separation from the component.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

//---------------------------------------------------------------------//

constructor(private _toastyService: ToastyService) { }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------//

handleError(error: any): void {
    console.log("Error", error)
    alert("Error")
    this.publishToast(error, "An unexpected error occured")
}//handleError

//---------------------------------------------------------------------//

publishToast(error: any, msg?: string) {
    console.log("Publishing Toast")

    let title = "Error " + (error.statusCode ? error.statusCode : '')
    let message = msg ? msg : ''
        + error.body ? error.body : ''

    // Create the instance of ToastOptions 
    var toastOptions: ToastOptions = {
        title: title,
        msg: message,
        showClose: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        theme: 'bootstrap',
        onAdd: (toast: ToastData) => {
        },
        onRemove: function (toast: ToastData) {
        }

    };
    this._toastyService.error(toastOptions);


}//addErrorToast

}//Cls
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because handleError() method is executed outside of the Angular "zone". To put it simply: Angular does not run the change detection mechanism after the handleError() call. The DOM is not updated so the toast is not visible.

Usually you don't need to worry about zones but ErrorHandler is one of the exceptions. If you want to run some code that needs to trigger change detection you need to explicitly wrap it inside a ngZone.run call like this:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { ToastyService } from 'ng2-toasty';

@Injectable()
export class AppErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(
        private toastyService: ToastyService,
        private ngZone : NgZone) { }

    handleError(error: any): void {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.publishToast(error, "An unexpected error occured");
        });  
    }
```

There are various blog posts about zones if you are interested in the details. For example:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html